# Моя следующая привилегия слишком длинная для трекера привилегий

Tags: дефект, профиль-участника, интерфейс

Моя следующая привилегия

> Просмотр голосов, развернутая карточка участника

слишком длинная, чтобы правильно отображаться в [трекере прогресса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223536/glorfindel?tab=topactivity):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема возникает только для моего собственного пользователя, но в нескольких браузерах (Safari и Firefox на macOS).